# Jenkins fails Jest tests that otherwise works (corporate proxy)

Tags: jenkins, proxy, jestjs, puppeteer

I am sitting behind corporate proxy.
So basically test is just page.goto("https://") I created Freestyle project and made it execute code in command line:

```
cd C:/Testing
npm test -- Jenkins
```

If I run these commands on machine where Jenkins is running, everything works and test passes. However, if I run it using Jenkins, this error appears:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Main Project
[Main Project] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7770552654778169643.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Main Project>cd C:/Testing 

C:\Testing>npm test -- Jenkins 

> testing@1.0.0 test C:\Testing
> jest "Jenkins"

FAIL .\Jenkins.test.js (5.023s)
  Describe
    Ã— Test (513ms)

  â—� Describe â€º Test

    net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://google.com/

      at navigate (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:539:37)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.587s
Ran all test suites matching /Jenkins/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked Jenkins HTTP Proxy Configuration and it was set up correctly (host, port and credentials are all correct), but if I enter https://google.com/ in Test URL and press "Validate Proxy", this error appears:

```
Failed to connect to https://google.com/ (code 407).
```

Is there something that can refuse Jenkins requests to websites? Windows Defender firewall is disabled.